# Guess-the-Number game gives answer too soon

Tags: python

I'm learning the introduction of Python and I run into a problem.

Please take a look at my script:

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
print (' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

#ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessesTaken in range (1,7):
    print ('take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print ('your guess is too low')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('your guess is too high')
    else:
        break

    if guess == secretNumber:
        print ('good job! you guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
    else:
        print ('nope. the number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

I am trying to do the guess-a-number game. When I run the script, it asks me:

1. Guess the number
2. When I enter in the number, it automatically gives me the number it stored instead of giving me the 6 tries I have.

If I was unclear at any steps, please let me know and I will do my best to answer more clear questions next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last part that starts with `if guess == secretNumber:` is part of the loop, but you don't want to give the final outcome during the loop. Instead put it after the loop (outside of it), which means you should reduce the indentation of those 4 lines of code:

```
import random
secretNumber = random.randint(1,20)
print (' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20.')

#ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessesTaken in range (1,7):
    print ('take a guess.')
    guess = int(input())

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print ('your guess is too low')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print ('your guess is too high')
    else:
        break

if guess == secretNumber:
    print ('good job! you guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
    print ('nope. the number i was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

Comment: Hi trincot! First, thank you about the spaces. Was making the changes and as i clicked submit, it said you have done it! Thank you, I understand how this works now. Second, I took it out like you said and it works! Did not notice that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to, as stated above already, simply move the last if statement out of the loop. The syntax you're using(other than that wrong indent) is very good which is a great start to python. However, in python 3, you dont need that else in the if statement inside the loop. Baisically,since you dont need to do anything if the ELSE condition is met, you can just take it out.

Comment: Im new to stack overflow, so im just trying to answer as many question as possible. Sorry for the repetition!